# ¿Cómo retornar un valor entero en un SP de SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un SP pequeño, que sólo hace una instrucción de if-else, verifica que un registro exista en una tabla, si existe quisiera poder retornar un 1, y si no existe que retorne un 0, ¿cómo puedo retornar un valor entero con el siguiente SP?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Oscar Navarro >
-- Create date: <27 Diciembre 2017>
-- Description: <Validar Carpetas no repetidas>
-- =============================================
Alter PROCEDURE  VerificaCarpeta
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @Nombre as nvarchar(max),
 @IdCategoriaPadre as bigint
AS
declare @Value int
if  Exists (select Top 1 Nombre from ValueCategoriaArchivo where Nombre = @Nombre)
and exists (select IdCategoriaPadre from ValueCategoriaArchivo where IdCategoriaPadre = @IdCategoriaPadre)

begin
set @Value =1
return @Value
end
else 
begin
set @Value =2
return @Value
end 
GO
```

Comment: Tal vez lo que quieres es un [FUNCTION](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) en vez de un `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Creo que deberías reconsiderarlo, los `Stored Procedure` cuando se ejecutan sin errores su valor de retorno es `Cero (0)` de lo contrario devuelve otros valores, los cuales puedes controlar (Del modo que lo planteas sería al revés de su funcionamiento natural) aunque lo puedes controlar. Pero como te comenta sstan, creo que te convendría más usar una `Function`

Comment: Perfecto, gracias a los 2 @sstan y J.Rodirugez, hace un rato estuve leyendo un poco acerca de las funciones y procedimientos almacenados, y me di cuenta que si ocupo una función para  lo que necesito hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retornar un valor entero desde un SP se hace tal como ya lo estás haciendo: `RETURN @Value`. Tal vez tu duda es más bien como poder usar este retorno, en tu ejemplo deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @RetValue INT

EXEC @RetValue = VerificaCarpeta @Nombre = 'Valor Nombre', @IdCategoriaPadre = 1

SELECT @RetValue
IF @RetValue = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Ejecución exitosa'
END
```

Algunas consideraciones:

- Ten en cuenta que `@RetValue` inicialmente al declararlo, es NULL y que en caso de algún error que eventualmente manejemos con un `TRY..CATCH`, no habremos capturado el valor de retorno, por lo que seguirá siendo NULL, de forma que no está de más controlar también el NULL en `@RetValue`.
- Además si reutilizas `@RetValue` para recuperar el valor de retorno de múltiples y distintos SP's, hay que asegurarse que todos retornen efectivamente un valor y tener en cuenta de no arrastrar valores de retorno de Sp's anteriores en la lógica, similar al punto anterior.
- Como ya te lo indicaron en los comentarios, lo más habitual que un valor de retorno `0` indica una ejecución exitosa, es común usar valores negativos para indicar distintos errores.